# What is wrong with my mapTo Statement

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

Trying to build something up but getting stuck and missing whatever the error is here. I want to track button clicks but get the value from the `#zip` input so thats why I chose `mapTo`. When I remove `mapTo` I can track clicks and change my statement  in the subscribe function to update the result div text with the contents of the `#zip` input (exactly as I am doing in `mapTo`) which confuses me because I think that shows the syntax is ok.

```
   Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('btn'),'click')
     .mapTo($('#zip').val())
      .subscribe(function(zipCode){
         $('#result').text(zipCode);
      });
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wegaceyefe/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do, you're trying to update `$('#result')` with current value of `$('#zip')` at the time the event occurs.

Operator `mapTo()` takes a single value as argument. This value is then used instead of every value coming from its source. In effect this means that `.mapTo($('#zip').val())` is initialized **just once** when you're creating the chain of Observables (even before you subscribe to it).

If you want it to be always the actual value you'll need some operator that takes a callback as a parameter. For example just `map()`:

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('btn'), 'click')
  .map(function(val) {
    return $('#zip').val();
  })
  .subscribe(function(zipCode){
    $('#result').text(zipCode);
  });
```

Your updated demo: http://jsbin.com/qepalo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: thank you for the full explanation of why this didn't work I appreciate it